# useEffect only if state changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have `useEffect` which calls an `action` from `redux` to fetch uploads

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getUploads()
}, [getUploads])
```

However, I only want to fetch when the state changes, not fetch everytime the component renders.
I have mapped the state like:

```js
{filteredUploads.map((image, i) => { return (...) })}
```

I have tried to add `getUploads`, `filteredUploads`, `filteredUploads.length` as dependency array. None of it worked.

My `redux-action`:

```js
export const getUploads = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOADING', payload: true })

        const res = await axios.get('/uploads/myuploads')
        dispatch({
            type: GETMYUPLOAD_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        })

    } catch (err) {
        const error = err.response.data.error[0].msg

        dispatch(setAlert(error, 'danger'))
    }
}
```

`mapStatetoProps`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { myuploads, searchField } = state.useruploads;
    return {

        searchField: state.useruploads.searchField,

        filteredUploads: myuploads.filter((upload) => upload.caption.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()))
    };
}
```

Comment: can you share `getUploads` as well?

Comment: useEffect calls getUploads each time this function changed: I suggest you to user useCallBack to define it

Comment: can you share the component code please

Comment: In order to provide a solution, its very important to see how getUploads is implemented and where

Comment: Is the issue that `useEffect` runs on every re-render (too many times) or only on mount (not enough times)?

Comment: `useEffect` runs on every re-render... I solved the `axios` request everytime I open the component by adding a `if statement` in `useEffect` to check if `state` is empty, if the state isn't empty it won't  make anymore axios requests. is this fine approach?

Answer (score 13):

To have the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook called when state updates, you'll need to include the relevant state variables in the dependency array of `useEffect` (the second argument passed to `useEffect`), which it seems you've attempted.

To address `useEffect` being called on every render of the component: this is happening because a value in the dependency array (`getUploads`) is changing, or being redefined, on every render. To fix this, you can use the [`useDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch) redux hook instead of `mapDispatchToProps`. The `useDispatch` hook provides a stable reference (meaning it won't change and cause `useEffect` to run) to the `dispatch` function from the Redux store.

Here's a full example:

```js
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getUploads } from "./redux-actions";


const MyComponent = props => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const [state, setState] = React.useState({});
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getUploads());
    }, [dispatch, state]);

    // rest of component
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain this. I did not get it